# How do I prevent my iPod nano's screen from going to sleep?

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I have broken my desk clock and am trying to use my square nano to show me time instead.

The problem is that when I set the screen to show time and leave it for some time the screen dims and eventually shuts off after which I have to get the screen back again by going to the menu.

Is there a way to make sure that the screen does not turn off? Dimming should be okay to save power, but it should at least show the time when I touch the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the stop watch and press start, now slide back to the watch face and it should stay on.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no a way to prevent the iPod nano from going to sleep mode.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but I still haven't tested it there is a menu called iTerm on the ipod nano 6g.You can enter it by clicking all buttons at once.Wait a few seconds and it will appear then you enter "power"--->"power drain mode" and it shoud keep the screen from locking.Of course it won't last long because the battery will be completly used-up.This is for more information.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YA9qcY-G3O0

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with my BOSE docking station.

1. Play music on loop
2. Open Clock

The iPod stays running.

Answer (score 1):

Settings>General>Date and time>Turn on the "Time on wake" feature.
Connect a headphone jack. Plug in charger. Play a song.  Press the power button once to turn the screen off and then again press it to bring the clock on. Now the clock should stay on even after you die as long as you dont disconnect the charger and the headphone jack . Cheers!

Thank me later.

Added tip: You can connect a broken headphone jack if you dont intend to listen to songs, to avoid the hassle of headphone wires.

Comment: I have this set up with a broken headphone male plug with my Nano running the clock in a 3d printed Mac Plus case(https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3110284).  Perfect little desk clock, and now I have the screen on full time. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I found was to let it go to sleep (save battery power) but set the power on button to bring up the clock first (in clock setting menu).
Note that if you then look at the music, for example, it will reset it back to show music first even though the switch says clock.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your iPod, browse the device (E:) and then in the direction bar type "ipod_control".

You will get into the Ipod_Control folder then change the properties so you can see all the hidden folders (Right-Click > Properties > Uncheck the Hidden box).

Then enter de Device Folder and you will se a file called "iPodSettings" open it on note pad.

And just simply search for the Energy Saver `<EnergySaver>1</EnergySaver>` and change the value to 0, Save the file and that's it your iPod now will never enter to SleepMode again.